# Capturar error y mostrar un dialogo para enviar informe en Android

Tags: android, diálogo

Buenas, he creado una app para android y funciona correctamente, pero a veces encuentra errores y sale un mensaje de forzar cierre y enviar informe, he notado que en aplicaciones como facebook o whatsapp aparte de mostrar el diálogo con los botones de forzar cierre y enviar informe aparece el botón esperar, ¿como podría crear algo similar en mi app ante un error?

Adjunto imagen de muestra:

[image: error image]

Comment: Otra libreria que he econtrado https://github.com/stkent/bugshaker-android

Answer (score 1):

Una opción para crear algo similar sería un DialogFragment, ejemplo:

```
public class DialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
   @Override
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
      builder.setPositiveButton("Continuar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            toast.makeText(this,"Continua",Toast.LENTH_SHORT).show();
         }
      })
      .setNegativeButton("Forzar cierre", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
toast.makeText(this,"Cierra",Toast.LENTH_SHORT).show()
            finish();
         });
         return builder.create();
      }
   }
}
```

Pero ese dialogo que muestras en realidad es generado por el sistema operativo, es algo llamado [ANR](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html) (Application Not Responding )

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con la librería [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra)
Parece fácil de implementar  y no requiere 100% tener un servidor, para recibir los informes, lo puedes enviar por email 
[Más información en su documentación](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Report-Destinations)

Ejemplo usando un servidor propio para recibir los informes:

```
@ReportsCrashes(formUri = "http://yourserver.com/yourscript",
                formUriBasicAuthLogin = "yourlogin", // optional
                formUriBasicAuthPassword = "y0uRpa$$w0rd", // optional
                mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
                resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)
public class MyApplication extends Application {
...
```

Para mostrar un dialogo de Error

```
@ReportsCrashes(formUri = "http://yourserver.com/yourscript",
                mode = ReportingInteractionMode.DIALOG,
                resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text, // optional, displayed as soon as the crash occurs, before collecting data which can take a few seconds
                resDialogText = R.string.crash_dialog_text,
                resDialogIcon = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info, //optional. default is a warning sign
                resDialogTitle = R.string.crash_dialog_title, // optional. default is your application name
                resDialogCommentPrompt = R.string.crash_dialog_comment_prompt, // optional. When defined, adds a user text field input with this text resource as a label
                resDialogEmailPrompt = R.string.crash_user_email_label, // optional. When defined, adds a user email text entry with this text resource as label. The email address will be populated from SharedPreferences and will be provided as an ACRA field if configured.
                resDialogOkToast = R.string.crash_dialog_ok_toast // optional. displays a Toast message when the user accepts to send a report.
                resDialogTheme = R.style.AppTheme_Dialog, //optional. default is Theme.Dialog
                )
public class MyApplication extends Application {
...
```